# Python pandas: can I add constraints like I would in a database?

Tags: python, pandas, constraints, referential-integrity

Is there any way to add constraints or foreign keys the way I would in a database? E.g. making sure a field is unique, a field is always > 0, that customer_id in the orders table always has a match in customer_id in the customer table, etc?

Comment: Not in a pandas df unless you define a class yourself and provide the logic before the data gets near a df

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to export the data to SQL and add the constraints there.