# Python - Pandas - Unique constraint for 'normal' column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Ist there something like a unique-constraint (like in sql) for 'normal' (not-index) columns in Pandas ?

Thanks

Egirus

Comment: I believe you would have to implement that yourself before you created the dataframe.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments from this answer makes some sense:

[Python pandas: can I add constraints like I would in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32353732/3645903)

You can’t directly put constraints on the pandas data frame. However you can always put constraints programmatically before putting data into the data frame.